# How can I use promises in an infinite loop with delay?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, es6-promise

```
require("./getSongFromSpotify")().then(a => {
    require("./instify")(a.artist,a.name).then(r => {
        if (r.status === "ok"){
            console.log("saved")
        }else{
            console.log("Instagram API have a problem!")
        }
    }).catch((r) => {console.error(r)})
}).catch((r) => {console.error(r)})
```

I need to execute this code in an infinite loop with 2000ms delay. How can I do this?

Comment: [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Comment: You need to execute some code in infinity loop with 2s delay. So is this question has anything related with "promises"?

Comment: I tried but i cant get any output

Comment: @tsh Yeah when i execute this code in any loop, it didnt wait for end promise

Comment: But you cannot guarantee the promise will be finished in 2s. Yes? If so... Do you want the next execution scheduled no matter the previous one finished? Or do you want the next execution been skipped when previous one not finished? Or do you want the next execution been scheduled 2s later after previous one finished, instead of the previous one started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `async` `await` syntax, this can be made to look quite straightforward:

```
const getSongFromSpotify = require("./getSongFromSpotify");
const instify = require("./instify");

const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function keepPolling() {
    while (true) { // forever (or until rejection)
        let song = await getSongFromSpotify();
        let result = await instify(song.artist, song.name);
        if (result.status === "ok") {
            console.log("saved");
        } else {
            console.log("Instagram API has a problem!");
        }
        await delay(2000);
    }
}

keepPolling().catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, stop requiring modules for the each execution. Let's declare those separately, this will also make the code more clear and readable:

```
const getSong = require('./getSongFrompotify');
const instify = require('./instify');
```

Now let's write a function which we will call recursively after two seconds passed from the previous execution finish and the promisified timer:

```
function waitFor(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  })
}

function doJob() {
  return getSong()
    .then(song => instify(song.artist, song.name))
    .then(result => {
      if (result.status === 'ok') {
        console.log('saved');
      } else {
        console.log('Problem!');
      }
    }) // no need to have 2 separate 'catch'
    .catch(err => console.error(err)) // all errors fall here
    .finally(() => waitFor(2000)) // anyway wait 2 seconds
    .then(() => doJob()); // and run all again
}
```

Now, we simply need to call it:

```
doJob();
```

Note, that this approach will result in endless loop (as you asked for), but I think you'll probably need to setup some additional variable/flag which will be checked before of each iteration in order to be able stop it.

Comment: You may just say `.then(doJob)` when you want `.then(() => doJob())`. Also, you are trying to return a promise which will never be resolved. It could be useless.

Comment: @tsh author asked for infinite loop, so yes, in this implementation it will not be resolved. However, I wrote that author probably will need to have a flag to indicate if job should be resolved instead of running next interation.